# In which comics did Batman become a murderer or a psychopath?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

List of comics in which Batman became a murderer or a psychopath? That is someone else had to stop Batman.

Comment: In addition to the examples listed in the linked question's answers, there's the _Flashpoint_ timeline, where Batman has much... laxed morals than usual.

Comment: Batman IS a psychopath.